# Validate presence of telephone number Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I am trying to validate the prescence of telephone numbers using rspec. I have set the telephone number to a string. I have the following code.

**Model**

```
  validates_presence_of :name, :address, :telephone, :email
  validates :email, :presence => true,
                    :format   => { :with => email_regex,:message => 'Enter valid email example@example.com ' }
end
```

**Factory**

```
Factory.define :company do |c|
  c.name "Example"
  c.address "123 Shark Road, London, England, SW1 9EP"
  c.telephone "(874)052-1258"  
  c.email "example@example.co.uk"
end
```

**Spec**

```
describe Company do
  before(:each) do
    @company = Factory(:company)
    @attr = {
      :name => "Example",
      :address => "123 Shark Road London England SW1 9EP",
      :telephone => "(874)052-1258",
      :email => "example@example.co.uk"

    }
  end
  it "should create a new instance given valid attributes" do
    Company.create!(@attr)

  end
  it "should commenters name" do
    no_comment_name = Company.new(@attr.merge(:name => ""))
    no_comment_name.should_not be_valid
  end
```

end

I am getting the following error:

> bundle exec rspec spec/models/company_spec.rb
>       /home/dj/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/
>   rspec-core-2.6.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:419:in `load': 
>   /home/***/******/spec/models/com
>       pany_spec.rb:10: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG,  expecting
>   tASSOC (SyntaxError)
>                :telephone " (874)052-1258", 
>                            ^
>       /home/***/******/spec/models/company_spec.rb:10: syntax error,
>   unexpected ',', expecting keyword_end
>                :telephone " (874)052-1258", 
>                                            ^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is in your before_each, here :telephone "(874)052-1258". You are missing the `=>`operator.